# API For Associating Cell Number With Provider

Tags: mobile, cellular-network

Given a cell number in the US (although other countries would be nice too), **how to I go about figuring out the provider?** Are there any web services that you know of or ETL dumps that I can use to get this information?

Ideally this component would accept a cell phone number and return a service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MX Telecom](http://www.mxtelecom.com/us/cl) looks most promising.  They have an XML interface detailed [here](http://www.localcallingguide.com/xmlquery.php).

Another [nice one](http://www.telcodata.us/telcodata/telco?npa=303&exchange=949) (pay to get CSV file)

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_number_portability#Number_Lookup_Services) is a list of other service providers.

Before local number portability, you could determine carrier by the 3 digits after area code.  This no longer works for people who "took their numbers with them" when they switched carriers.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about other countries. [Here is a list](http://www.crankup.net/mobile-phone-number-codes-india-only) of codes for Indian mobile phones. I am not aware of any webservice available. But this can stored in a DB and referred.